# Checking for cookies being enabled in IE8 using Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies, internet-explorer-8

I am attempting to check whether cookies are enabled or not using Javascript, cross-browser.

I have got this working fine in Firefox 3 using the following code -

```
var cookieEnabled=(navigator.cookieEnabled)? true : false;

//if not IE4+ nor NS6+
if (typeof navigator.cookieEnabled=="undefined" && !cookieEnabled){ 
    document.cookie="testcookie";
    cookieEnabled=(document.cookie.indexOf("testcookie")!=-1)? true : false;
}
```

And from what I've seen this seems to be the reasonably established method of checking for cookie support being turned on? However, it refuses to work in IE8, when I turn off cookies in that and run this code cookiesEnabled always equals true.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm seeing on IE8 - even if i Block All cookies, and try to set one via my javascript code it gets set and i can see the actual cookie on the file system. One exception to this rule is when i set a domain for the cookie, it does not get set. So i'm wondering whether the javascript and navigator.cookieEnabled when run via a local HTML file returns true - but if you were to run it over a remote web server (as served from a domain) - does it behave differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah found the problem. I was testing my software by navigating to http://localhost...

Of course IE treats this as the Local Intranet Zone and doesn't apply my settings for cookies, so allowing them regardless!

If I navigate to my actual IP address via the local loopback it treated it as internet zone and worked fine :)

Doh!